# Array not working properly , strange output shows

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

On my angular 4 app I have an object named allAvailableProviders as follows 
where 71, 72 are provider ids and then time-stamp and then time in 24 hour format

```
71: {…}
  1514678400: […]
    0: 800
    1: 1300
  1515283200: […]
    0: 800
    1: 1300
  1515888000: […]
    0: 800
    1: 1300
72: {…}
  1514678400: […]
    0: 800
    1: 1300
  1515283200: […]
    0: 800
    1: 1300
  1515888000: […]
    0: 800
    1: 1300
```

I wrote a function to create a new array with above object as follows

```
1514678400: []
  800: []
   0: 71
   1: 72
  1300: []
   0: 71
   1: 73
```

Following is my code

```
let allDates = [];
  for(let pid in this.allAvailableProviders)
  {
    for(let slotDate in this.allAvailableProviders[pid]){
      if(!Array.isArray(allDates[slotDate])){
        allDates[slotDate] = new Array();
      }
      for(let spots in this.allAvailableProviders[pid][slotDate]){
        if(!Array.isArray(allDates[slotDate][spots])){
          allDates[slotDate][spots] = new Array();
        }
        allDates[slotDate][spots].push(pid);
      }

    }
  }
  console.log(allDates)
```

On console log its showing following output

```
Array [ <10 empty slots>, … ]

[…]
[0…99999999]
[100000000…199999999]
[200000000…299999999]
[300000000…399999999]
[400000000…499999999]
[500000000…599999999]
[600000000…699999999]
[700000000…799999999]
```

I am not sure what is happening here but when I try to build this with jquery it works properly but not with javascript and typescript

Is there any way to get the desired output ?

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON data?  What did you do with jQuery that doesn't work here?

Answer (score 1):

I have only headcompiled your code, but it looks like:

```
for(let pid in this.allAvailableProviders)
```

Should be:

```
for(let pid of this.allAvailableProviders)
```

In JavaScript/TypeScript the `for`-`of` loop is the one you use to iterate items in an array. The `for`-`in` loop iterates keys (in the case of an array, the index)...

```
var arr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

// 0, 1, 2, 3
for (let item in arr) {
    console.log(item);
}

// A, B, C, D
for (let item of arr) {
    console.log(item);
}
```